# The distributional gradient of the closest isometry to the differential of a smooth map

Tags: riemannian-geometry, soft-question, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

**The setting-a "linear algebra" fact:**

Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix, and suppose that $\det A<0$ and that the singular values of $A$ are *distinct*. Then, there exist a *unique* matrix $Q(A) \in \text{SO}_n$ which is closest to $A$.

(Closest w.r.t the Frobenius norm, i.e. the standard Euclidean distance). Furthermore, if we define 
$$V=\{ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \, | \,\, A \in \text{GL}_n^- \, \, \text{and has distinct singular values}\},$$ then the map $A \to Q(A)$, considered as a map $V \to \text{SO}_n$, is smooth. (There is explanation at the end, if you are interested).

---

**Differential geometry:**

Let $\mathbb{D}^n$ be the closed $n$-dimensional unit ball ,and let $f:\mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be real-analytic . Set 
$$U= \{ p \in \mathbb{D}^n \, | \, df_p \in \text{GL}_n^- \, \, \text{and has distinct singular values.}\}$$

**Assume that $U$ has full measure in $ \mathbb{D}^n$.**

For every $p \in U$, let $q_p:=Q(df_p) \in \text{SO}_n$ be the unique special orthogonal matrix which is closest to $df_p$. By our assumption, $q$ is well-defined a.e. on $\mathbb{D}^n$.

> **Question:** Can we say something non-trivial about the distributional gradient of $q$? What can we say about the difference between the distributional gradient and the classical gradient, which is defined everywhere on $U$? e.g. does it have a definite sign?

As I will now explain, $q$ does not always lie in a Sobolev space, even though $q|_U$ is smooth; when we approach points where $df$ has repeating singular values, bad "jumps" can occur: Indeed, set

$A=\begin{pmatrix} -\sigma_1 & 0 \\\ 0 & \sigma_2 \end{pmatrix}$. Then
$$Q(A) =
\begin{cases}
\text{Id},  & \text{if  } \, 0<\sigma_1 < \sigma_2  \\
-\text{Id}, & \text{if  } \, 0<\sigma_2 < \sigma_1
\end{cases},$$
thus when $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ "cross" each other, we get a jump in $Q$.

Here is a concrete example: Consider $f(x,y)=(-x-\frac{x^2}{2},y+\frac{y^2}{2})$ as a function on $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ (the ball with radius $\epsilon$ centered at the origin): Then
$$df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} -(1+x) & 0 \\\ 0 & 1+y \end{pmatrix},$$

hence $q=Q(df)=\begin{cases}
\text{Id},  & \text{if  } \, x < y  \\
-\text{Id}, & \text{if  } \, y < x
\end{cases}$

does not belong to $W^{1,p}(B_{\epsilon} (0),\mathbb{R}^{4})$ for any $p \ge 1$.

---

*Explanation on why $q$ is smooth on $U$:*

For $p \in U$, $q_p$ can be expressed as follows: Let $df=U\Sigma V^T$ be the SVD of $df$. Then $q=UD V^T$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix obtained from $\Sigma$, by replacing the smallest singular value with $-1$, and all other singular values by $1$.
Since locally, [we can choose the matrices $U,V$ smoothly](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3163368/104576), this implies that $q$ is smooth on $U$.

Comment: Have you tried use Lojasiewicz's inequality?

Comment: Setting $n=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$ gives $q(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x)$ which is not in $W^{1,1}(\mathbb R,\mathbb R).$ The restriction to harmonic functions rules out this example at least.

Comment: @Dap Thank you! This is a nice observation. Actually, I was more interested in the behaviour of the minimizer in $\text{SO}_n$ (rather then the orthogonal polar factor itself; they coincide only for matrices with positive determinant). I thought it would be simpler to start with looking at the polar factor, as it is given by a single "expression" on the entire domain. Your comment made me understand this was hopeless, due to the possible "jumps". I have now edited the question, so the object of study is the projection on $\text{SO}_n$. Thank you for your insight, again.